# Lingering open files resulting in "Too many open files"

Tags: c++, file, boost

I have code using boost to list directory contents, iterate through each file, and do some data processing stuff. The results are being printed to an output file ('histFile').
After ~2555 files have been processed, I get the error:

> boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Too many open files: "/Users/.../.../.../directory_with_files"

My code is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    FILE *histFile;
    string outputFileName = "somename";
    bool ifRet = initFile(histFile, outputFileName.c_str(), "a");   // 1
    fclose(histFile);                                               // 2
}
```

If I comment out the last two lines above ('1' and '2'), the code finishes fine.  Thus it seems copies of 'histFile' are being left open, but I don't understand how!  This is the operative part of the method:

```
bool initFile(FILE *&ofFile, const char *fileName, const char *openType, int overwriteOption) {

if(overwriteOption < 0 || overwriteOption > 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: ToolBox - initFile() : unknown 'overwriteOption' (%d), setting to (0)!\n", overwriteOption);
}

// Read-Only
if(openType == "r") {
    if(ofFile = fopen(fileName, "r")) { return true; }
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not open file (%s)!\n", fileName);
    return false;
}

// Appending:
if(openType == "a" || openType == "a+") {
    // Check if file already exists
    if(!fopen(fileName, "r")){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: (%s) File does not Exist, cannot append!\n", fileName);
        return false;
    }   
    if(ofFile = fopen(fileName, openType)) { return true; }     
}

// Writing:
//    if file already exists
if(FILE *temp = fopen(fileName, "r")){
    if(overwriteOption == 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: (%s) File Exists!\n", fileName);
        return false;
    }
    if(overwriteOption == 1) {

    }
    if(overwriteOption == 0) {
        char backupFileName[TB_CHARLIMIT], backupPrefix[TB_CHARLIMIT];
        strcpy(backupFileName, fileName);                                  // copy filename
        // create a prefix w/ format '<YYYYMMDD>BACKUP_'
        DateTime now;
        sprintf(backupPrefix, "%s", now.getDateStr().c_str());
        strcat(backupPrefix, "BACKUP_");
        // add to copied filename, and move file
        strcpy(backupFileName, prependFileName(backupFileName, backupPrefix));
        moveFile(fileName, backupFileName);
    }   
    fclose(temp);
} 

if(ofFile = fopen(fileName, openType)) { return true; }


// Default: Return error and false 
fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not open file (%s)!\n", fileName);
return false;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with pointers/references?
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying the code you posted shows the problem?  I don't see any boost in there, so what does boost::filesystem have to do with the problem?

Comment: You probably need to show the rest of `initFile` - I suspect it is throwing an exception which is then leaking an open file.

Comment: @Paur R: If it threw an exception, then the rest of the loop wouldn't get executed. So that can't be it.

Comment: @TonyK And that also means that no more files will be opened. And if the exception is not caught the program will terminate and all files will be closed so no leaking file handles in either case.

Comment: OK - I think it would still be useful to see the rest of `initFile` though

Comment: @MichaelBurr Well, if I comment out the code shown, the problem is fixed.  So probably.  Boost is checking directories which eventually throws the problem, but that doesn't mean its the cause.

Comment: @PaulR I've added the additional code; but I was thinking along the lines of TonyK's response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're leaking a handle in this bit of code when you're testing if the file exists already:

```
// Appending:
if(openType == "a" || openType == "a+") {
    // Check if file already exists

    if(!fopen(fileName, "r")){     //  <-- the FILE* opened here is leaked

        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: (%s) File does not Exist, cannot append!\n", fileName);
        return false;
    }   
    if(ofFile = fopen(fileName, openType)) { return true; }     
}
```

Is there really a reason to make that check? Why not just let the file be created if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: Thanks!  That's it.  No 'real' reason; just cleanliness.